# Whenever I refresh page its path copy again and again angular routing issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

Whenever I go to my landing page and if I refresh it then it add one more path to the landing page any solution you can refer images for more information

```
const appRoutes:Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        redirectTo:'DiscussionRoom',
        pathMatch:'full'
    },
    {
        path:'DiscussionRoom',
        loadChildren:()=>import('./modules/discussion/discussion.module').then(m=>m.DiscussionModule)
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like an unproblematic routing configuration. You'll need to add some more info so that the problem can be re-produced.

Comment: @Filburt added in text

Comment: Do you have a module for discussion routing configuration?